# Cannot convert float to Decimal. First convert float to a string

Tags: python, django, decimal

I get the following error:

> 02/08 09:15:45> Decimal price: 0.00
>
> 02/08 09:15:45> Decimal price = None
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string

Here is my code:

```
            s.price = Decimal("%.2f" % (float(request.data['subscription_price'])))
            log('Decimal price: %s' % s.price)
            
            if s.price == Decimal("0.00"):
                s.price = None
                log('Decimal price = None')
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?  I tried a hack to avoid saving a 0.00 in the database via the "if s.price == Decimal("0.00"):" ... to no avail.

Comment: This code can't produce the output you give as there's no code after the 'Decimal price = None' log statement. Also there should be a traceback.

Comment: The code snippet you included wouldn't create this error- the error is likely caused by later code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert float number to Decimal with two decimal places this is working code:

```
import Decimal
In [10]: a = 7.3656
In [11]: Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
Out[11]: Decimal('7.37')
```

More info about working with decimal numbers you can find here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if str(s.price) == str(Decimal("0.00")):
   s.price = None
   log('Decimal price = None')
```

Comment: Hi, 10 Rep.
Thanks for editing my mistakes.
Do you think my answer is right?